# Servlet can be accessed directly against localhost but not when accessed after site name

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have written and compiled a servlet, which I have added to my `WEB-INF/classes` folder and updated the `web.xml` file to map to `/MyServlet`.

This is working in that I can navigate to `http://localhost:8080/MyServlet` and get the expected result.

I am now expecting to be able to access this servlet by navigating to `http://localhost:8080/MySite.html/MyServlet` however this is giving me a 404 error.

I can access `http://localhost:8080/MySite.html` without problem, and the html file is sitting at the same level as the `WEB-INF` folder. It seems that the site is not able to access the `classes` folder, so is there another setting I need to change to fix this?

Comment: It is DynamicWebApplication project?

Comment: I'd originally written the servlet in a JavaEE Application Client project, but I just tried creating a new Dynamic Web Application project and still get the same result - I can access the servlet directly against `localhost` but not as a backslash after the actual site

Comment: *"I am now expecting to be able to access this servlet by navigating to http://localhost:8080/MySite.html/MyServlet"* - but why? MySite.html is apparently not a site name, just the name of another resource (a html file in this case). If you go to /MySite.html the browser will fetch the html file, if you go to /MyServlet the browser will fetch the content produced by the servlet. I don't see anything wrong besides your expectations.

Comment: @CrazyHorse: Gimby is right. But for your approach, may be try correct url of your servlet in web.xml. As for you map your servlet class to  /MySite.html/MyServlet

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. So the only thing that was wrong was my understanding. @Gimby - if you want to make your response the answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I am now expecting to be able to access this servlet by navigating to localhost:8080/MySite.html/MyServlet"* - This is a misunderstanding.

MySite.html is apparently not a site name but just the name of another resource - a html file in this case. If you go to `/MySite.html` the browser will fetch the html file, if you go to `/MyServlet` the browser will fetch the content produced by the servlet.